# How to align two elements side by side and center them

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to copy the Harvard about page as an exercise in order to learn css. The problem I've come upon is that I cannot for the life of me center the navbar and the article element I've got on the page.

I've managed to align the article and navbar side by side by putting them both in a div element and specifying the width as 100%, then making the navbar and article elements 50% of the width each.

This is what I got so far:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1JvL.jpg

Here's my css:

```
div { 
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
    width: 100%; 
}

nav { 
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: top; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

article { 
    width: 50%; 
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-right: 80px; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    float: right;
    margin-top: -250px;
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: So what is the problem? Are you looking for text-align: center?

Comment: How do I center everything so it's in the middle of the page

Comment: text-align: center centers everything on the page, it looks ugly: https://imgur.com/a/CpRJKCG

Comment: I'm trying to make it look like this: https://imgur.com/a/IGRDBTB

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to horizontally center an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-an-element)

Comment: Surely if your element is 100% width then you cannot centre it as it takes the full width?  If you are trying to achieve something more like your image, then you need to give your container a max-width and margin  auto instead of 100% width - also I wouldn't use a bare div selector like that as it will apply that style to all divs